# Mock Realm interface and functions in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, unit-testing, testing, realm

I am currently testing a component that consumes results(Salaries) returned by Realm database and sort them  as follows using sorted function from Results interface defined in Realm itself.

```
salaries.sorted('timestamp', true)[salaries.length - 1].pop
```

When i run tests it gives the following error :

> TypeError: salaries.sorted is not a function

Which makes sense as sorted is not mocked in tests.

I found a mocking module for realm database [here](https://gist.github.com/hyb175/beb9ceed4c34300ba7c77d3d6d44ae52) but has partial implementation of it.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: We need complete and minimal code. See Please review [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also what's the expected result of this `[salaries.length - 1].pop`?